# How to extract fc7 features from AlexNet in pytorch as numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I want to extract the `4096`-dimensional feature vector from the `fc7` layer of my finetuned AlexNet. My goal is to use this layer for clustering later on.
This is how I extract it:

```
alexnet = models.alexnet(pretrained=True);
fc7 = alexnet.classifier[6];
```

However, when I print it, `fc7` is a `Linear` object:

```
Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
```

What I am looking for is how to turn this `Linear` object into a numpy array so that I can do further manipulations on it. 
What I am thinking of is to call its method`'def forward(self, input)'`, but am not sure which input to provide? Should I provide the input image or should I provide the output the fc6 layer?

And I want the `4096`-dim input array and get rid of the `1000` output array (presumably, since I don't think it will help me for clustering).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done by creating a new model with all the same layers (and associated parameters) as `alexnet` except for the last layer.

```
new_model = models.alexnet(pretrained=True)
new_classifier = nn.Sequential(*list(new_model.classifier.children())[:-1])
new_model.classifier = new_classifier
```

You should now be able to provide the input image to `new_model` and extract a 4096-dimensional feature vector.

If you do need a particular layer as a numpy array for some reason, you could do the following: `fc7.weight.data.numpy()`.

(on PyTorch 0.4.0)

Comment: Using this fc7.weight.data.numpy() will give you the weights not the neurons output (features). He asked for the features for clustering, not the weights.